# iOS adding huge number of products through In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm working on in iphone application for my company, they want to sell huge number of products using in-app-purchase ...

but the problem is to use iap we have to add for each product a record on app store contains meta data and its price about this product, and as I said before we have huge data.
So what I'm thinking about is to add a number of virtual products each one with a different tier price and when a user buy a product form my store I map this product with one of the virtual product on app store (depending on the price tier) and I send an identifier through SKMutableProduct.requestData and receive it with the transaction to know which product the user has bought.

In this way if I have millions of products with 5 tires price I can add just 5 products to app store, But I don't if apple will accept that ... is that regular ? what do you think ?
if not what can I do with huge number of products?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Application Loader provides the ability to bulk upload IAP product information from a flat file.

Go to iTunes Connect->Manage Your Applications, then scroll to the bottom and download the app loader (if you haven't already) and select "View Guide".    You'll want to look at the "Creating a Package from a File" section.

Answer (score 1):

No that isn't regular and Apple would not allow this. It's important to have an entry per product in iTunes Connect. The way you are proposing would not work if the user restored purchases.

Also the nature of non consumable products is that they are purchased once and forever owned, this would not work with how you are suggesting because you can't purchases a non consumable twice.

Answer (score 0):

With the Application Loader on OS X and a CSV upload in the Google Play Developer console you have the possibility to upload multiple In-App-Pruchasing-Products in one go. To streamline the process I made a small tool that helps you generate these files. If you need more customizing it is also be a good starting point to teach you all the ins and outs.

You can check the whole thing out here: http://niklausgerber.typed.com/blog/an-easy-way-to-generate-batch-upload-files-for-in-app-purchase-items-for-itunes-connect-and-google-play-developer-console