# How to upload multiple in App purchase to the Appstore

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, in-app

I want to upload more than 1000 products to the App Store. After lot googling I find out to upload via Application Loader , so I download Xcode Version 10 , there was Application Loader but  not found to upload In App Purchase content . Please guide me to upload multiple products to the App Store, already prepare excel sheet for it .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS adding huge number of products through In-App Purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873314/ios-adding-huge-number-of-products-through-in-app-purchase)

Comment: No this one is old methodology which is no more in use